# Why can't I create a group of circles with a dataset more than once in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dataset

m creating a scatter plot and I have problems plotting my circles (datapoints).

When appending the first set of circles it is drawn fine on the graph. However the next set I try to append won't be draw for some reason. How can this be? Am I using the Enter/append/select wrong the 2nd time?

I have a JSFiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/4wptM/

I have uncommented the parts where I load and manipulate my data and created the same array with a smaller sample. As it can be seen only the first set of circles are shown and the 2nd ones aren't.

My code of the circle section is pasted below:

```
    var circle = SVGbody
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(graphData[0])
            .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(100);})
                .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))})
                .attr("r",5);

    circle = SVGbody
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(graphData[1])
            .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(200);})
                .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))})
                .attr("r",5);
```

I just have those 2 copied to try and figure out the problem. The actual code I have is in the following for loop. When I run it in this loop it draws the circles for when the index is 1 and a few of when the index is 3.

```
    for(var i = 0;i < graphData.length;i++){
        var circle = SVGbody
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(graphData[i])
            .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx",function(d){return xScale((i*100)+100);})
                .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))})
                .attr("r",20);
        //console.log(i + "   :::::::   " + graphData[i])
    }
```

Some help would be so greatly appretiated. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why you've asked the same question 10 hours later a second time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851064/why-cant-i-create-a-group-of-circles-twice-in-d3

Comment: It was a mistake. I deleted the old one now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When operating on a existing set of elements (as it is the case here on the second `.selectAll("circle")` the `.data()` method uses only these elements from the array which have no corresponding index in the selecton made with `.selectAll()`. To prevent this behaviour you will have to add a key function as the second parameter of `.data()` as explained [here](http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.de/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html) and [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data).

Here this function only has to return each element of the array:

```
function (d) {
    return d;
}
```

In the fiddle it would look something like this:

```
var circle = SVGbody
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(graphData[0], function(d) { return d; })  // <-- this one
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(100);})
                .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))})
                .attr("r",5);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/)

And to change the fill color of an element you have to use `.style("fill", ...)` and not `.attr("fill", ...)`

```
.style("fill", "green")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me out a lot. After applying circles with my data instead of some test circles I had earlier, my zoom started malfunctioning. It zooms in fine but pushes all of the circles to the left. Do know why this happens?